# converting map to json gives a lot of integers in golang

Tags: json, dictionary, go, marshalling

I'm trying to convert a map to a JSON string. But my code below seems to yield an array of numbers.

Here is my main.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type column struct {
  field string
  fieldType string
}

type tblSchema struct {
  tbl string
  columns map[string]column
}
func main() {
    mapper := make(map[string]tblSchema)
    columns := make(map[string]column)
    columns["first"] = column{field:"user_id",fieldType:"int(11)"}
    mapper["t_user"] = tblSchema{tbl:"t_user",columns:columns}
    jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(mapper)
    log.Println(jsonString)
    //log.Println(mapper)
}
```

This produces the following output

```
[123 34 116 95 117 115 101 114 34 58 123 125 125]
```

If I uncomment `log.Println(mapper)`, I get

```
map[t_user:{t_user map[first:{user_id int(11)}]}]
```

**What am I doing wrong?  I expect jsonString to have the following format**

```
{
    "t_user":{
        "tbl":"t_user",
        "columns":{
            "first":{
                "field":"user_id",
                "fieldType":"int(11)"
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)
```

returns `[]byte` so you need to convert it to `string`:

```
log.Println(string(jsonString))
```

---

EDIT

This will yield the desired result

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Column struct {
  Field string
  FieldType string
}

type TblSchema struct {
  Tbl string
  Columns map[string]Column
}
func main() {
    mapper := make(map[string]TblSchema)
    columns := make(map[string]Column)
    columns["first"] = Column{Field:"user_id",FieldType:"int(11)"}
    mapper["t_user"] = TblSchema{Tbl:"t_user",Columns:columns}
    jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(mapper)
    log.Println(string(jsonString))
    log.Println(mapper)
}
```

Comment: Also, struct fields need to be exported.  The json from this is `{"t_user":{}}` because tblSchema and column don't have exported fields.